# Does extra damage chance improve Lifesteal output?

Tags: dota-2

Does extra damage from chance based abilities (e.g. `Sniper's Headshot`, `Slardar's Bash`) give `Lifesteal` if you have respective item or is `Lifesteal` calculated only from raw damage?

Does the same apply to MKB Mini-Bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Lifesteal#Lifesteal_and_other_Abilities

The rule is quite simple, only physical bashs are taken into account in the lifesteal formula.

http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Bash#Sources_of_Bash

Sniper's, Slardar's = yes
MKB's = no